# Is there a Stack Exchange site for questions about welding and plasma cutters and metal fabrication?

Tags: support

I would like to get "peer-reviewed" answers to questions about hobbyist/small-project welding and plasma cutters, and fabrication in general.  Is there a stack-exchange site for that?

Or to put the question another way, how do I suggest a new site?

Comment: [Personal Manufacturing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22246/personal-manufacturing) was an interesting beta site that could have also been a fit for this, but it was shut down for not having enough activity. That's too bad, I was hoping that would do well.

Comment: @Brad: But its focus would have to be broadened considerably: "Making things with computers" is too narrow and may even alienate people interested in working "with their hands".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this proposal in the definition stage: [Fabrication, Welding & Machining](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39711/fabrication-welding-machining). I don't know if that would be a good fit. Have a look at it and perhaps help in its definition.

And in general for new Q&A suggestions you will have to go to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)

Comment: excellent fit. Sample questions right on the money.

Comment: Proposal has been deleted :(

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to get [help from the DIY folks](https://diy.stackexchange.com/faq), but that may be outside their wheelhouse.

> Home Improvement - Stack Exchange is for contractors and (serious) DIY'ers.
>
> This can include topics such as:
>
> - Questions you would typically ask a home contractor.
> - Which tools and materials to use for a specific task.
> - Best practices for a specific task.
> - Identifying the source or cause of a problem within your home.
> - National building codes (of any country).
> - Installation, maintenance and repair of major appliances.

Comment: DIY would be too all-encompassing, and the signal-to-noise ratio would be unacceptable for those interested in metal fabrication. Not that fixing a toilet, getting windows unstuck, and tiling a backsplash is noise :-)